# VBA Checkmark - Return 'Yes' if double clicked and removed

Tags: excel, vba

I use the below VBA code to display a checkmark/tick when a cell is double clicked. At times, the checkmark/tick needs to be removed. To remove the checkmark/tick, the cell needs to be double clicked again. Once double clicked to remove the checkmark/tick, the cell return as blank. My question is; would it be possible to display the word ‘YES’ rather than having the cell blank?

Or as an even better option, is it possible to return the original text (before the cell was even double clicked) in the cell when double clicked (to remove checkmark/tick) rather than return as blank?

I hope this makes sense! Thank you in advance!

Below is the VBA code I have used for the checkmark/tick:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    On Error GoTo 1
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2:Z200")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        If Target.Value = ChrW(&H2713) Then
            Target.ClearContents
            Cancel = True
        Else
            Target.Value = ChrW(&H2713)
            Cancel = True
        End If
    End If

    On Error GoTo 0
1   Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To display the word "YES" change the line :

```
Target.ClearContents
```

With:

```
Target.Value = "YES"
```

***Full Code***

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    On Error GoTo 1
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2:Z200")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        If Target.Value = ChrW(&H2713) Then
            Target.Value = "YES"
        Else
            Target.Value = ChrW(&H2713)
        End If
        Cancel = True
    End If

    On Error GoTo 0
1   Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This will replace the original value with a checkmark and then restore the original value on re-clicking, but it only works for text values and only changes the *appearance* of the cell...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2:Z200")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo haveError
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        If Target.NumberFormat Like ";;;*" Then
            Target.NumberFormat = "General"
        Else
            Target.NumberFormat = ";;;" & ChrW(&H2713)
        End If
        Cancel = True
    End If

haveError:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```